# Having Log in & Session Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

First I'd like to let you know I can successfully create a new user and start a session for that new user. What I cannot do is then log in as that new user.

Not to distract anyone from answering but I think the error is within Authenticating the User.

Currently if in the sessions controller. If I have the below.

`user = User.find_by(params[:email])
 if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])`

I will get redirected to the login page because the password doesn't match.
I can login if I have the below. But I will not start the session as the correct user.

`user = User.find_by(params[:email])
 if user`

Again I can create new users, my user count does increase, but I cannot log in with the user once I end the session.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
user = User.find_by(params[:email])
 if user && user.authenticate(params[:session])
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  case user.admin_level
    when 1 
      session[:site_admin] = true 
      session[:can_create_post] = true
    when 2 
      session[:creator] = true
      session[:can_create_post] = true

    when 3
      session[:friend] = true
      session[:can_comment_on_post] = true
  end
  if params[:remember_me]
  cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
  else
    cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
  end
  log_in user
  redirect_to user, :notice => "Logged in!"
else
 flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
  redirect_to root_url
end
end

def loggedin?
@user = session[:user_id]
redirect_to page_path(current_user)
end

def destroy
log_out if logged_in?
cookies.delete(:auth_token)
session.clear
redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
end

def session_params
  params.require(:session).permit(:user_id)
end

end
```

My User Model Looks like below

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :remember_token, :image
 before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }
 mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
 mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
 validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
 before_save { email.downcase! }
 before_save { name.capitalize! }
 VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
 validates :email, presence: true , length: { maximum: 255 },
            format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
 has_secure_password
 validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true

 def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ?     BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
end 

def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
end

def forget
  update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
end

def authenticated?(remember_token)
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
end




def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end

def authenticated?(remember_token)
BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
end

end
```